# Is buying a localized domain and redirecting it to my main site a good idea for SEO?

Tags: seo, domains, multiple-domains, local-seo

I want to set up a couple of URLs to point to my main site. For example, if I were an SEO expert in London, would it be a good idea to buy the domain `seo-expert-london.com` (which would then redirect to my main site) in order to try and gain more business from London?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see an advantage to doing this. You are never going to replace ranking well for your original site. Buying another domain name does not really add any value that I can see. You gotta remember that keyword domain names do not really add rank and one that just redirects *really* does not add rank.